# Failed to enumerate subscribed files-no mods

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, mods

I got the "Failed to enumerate subscribed files" error, which I know means that I have over 50 subscribed files.

Thing is, I didn't. I thought one of them was bugged, so I favorited them all and unsubscribed. I still received the message with no mods installed.

All the mods I had were working at the same time, and I don't see any changes I did that were so horrible.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling Skyrim?

Answer (score 1):

[This forum thread over at the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=30278271&postcount=13) has a comment by a user with the username suchotek having a similar problem to you, having only a handful of modifications installed but receiving an error indicating more than 50.

This person fixed the issue by removing the following registry key;

> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam\Apps\72850
> ```

As always, remember to backup your registry before making any changes.

This forum thread also has a couple of suggestions to prevent this from happening in the future;

- To have a mod installed you don't *have* to be subscribed to it, unsubscribe to mods that are stable and you don't think will receive further updates, then you can subscribe to more
- The 50 mod limit is specific to Steam Worksop, mods installed in Nexus do not count towards this limit

[It is mentioned](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=29170130&postcount=10) that this issue is a bug, but I don't have anything beyond a forum post to cite so this is possibly untrue, and this could have how Valve intended this to work. For more discussion in relation to this issue [check out this long thread, also on the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2528739).

Comment: Yeah - I put that in there so that if anybody came back saying "ZOMG I FOLLOWED YOUR INSTRUCTIONS AND IT BROKE!" I can point to the backup line and not lose sleep